# std::stream write / read vs operator << / operator >>

Tags: c++, std, iostream

For `std::stream` / `ostream` / `istream` / `...`: What is the difference between using operators `<<` and `>>` or using `write()` and `read()` methods ?

I suppose for binary writing/reading you should use `write`/`read`, but Is there any difference for text/ASCII ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`write` and `read` do not understand anything about the data being printed - for them all there is are bytes. `<<` and `>>` on the other hand understand what you print and can be overloaded only for a given datatype. As a consequence read and write are generally faster - no complex logic happens, we simply print bytes to the stream.

Comment: ... Also, this does not touch on the text / binary file divide, which is handled at a lower layer.

Comment: `read` and `write` themselves are certainly faster, but because they deal in unformatted data, we have to add formatting functions to insert data into and extract it out of the buffer.  (Admittedly, formatting binary data is typically faster than formatting text, but you still can't ignore it completely.)